# SqlException was unhandled by c# - in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, inner-join, using

So I'm trying to run my code when i get this error:

*An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'b'.*

The code looks like this:

```
            string query = "select a.Navn from Ejer a" +
                       "INNER JOIN SlipsEjer b ON a.Id = b.EjerId" +
                       "Where b.SlipsId = SlipsId";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlipsId", SlipsLB.SelectedValue);

            DataTable ejerTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(ejerTable);

            EjerLB.DisplayMember = "Navn";
            EjerLB.ValueMember = "Id";
            EjerLB.DataSource = ejerTable;
        }
```

I don't know why.. I've tried and run it through a new query in Sql and it works fine there..

Really hope u guys can help! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space at the end of each line. Also add a @ symbol for the parameter.

```
string query = "select a.Navn from Ejer a " +
               "INNER JOIN SlipsEjer b ON a.Id = b.EjerId " +
               "Where b.SlipsId = @SlipsId";
```

Someone suggested using a verbatim string in the comment. Here's a sample of verbatim string. You can easily copy your query from Management Studio. Although I prefer using a stored procedure.

```
string query = @"
select a.Navn from Ejer a
INNER JOIN SlipsEjer b ON a.Id = b.EjerId
Where b.SlipsId = @SlipsId
";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Yeah, i had a @ before, must have deleted it by mistake!
But didn't know the spaces would do the trick! Thank you @Handoko.Chen

Comment: Also using the Verbatim character `@` will be of great help to avoid these mistakes.

Comment: If you don't add a space, it will be like this: `select a.Navn from Ejer aINNER JOIN SlipsEjer b ON a.Id = b.EjerIdWhere b.SlipsId = @SlipsId`.